# Error when sending string over to another java class

Tags: android, string, listener

I am currently trying to send in two string values from one java class to another. Basically I am trying to send "origin" and "destination" over from `MapsActivity` to `DirectionFinder` class.

**MapsActivity.java**

```
private void getDirections() {
    String origin = "Disneyland";
    String destination = "Universal Studios";

    try {
        new DirectionFinder(this, origin, destination).execute(); //error
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**DirectionFinder.java**

```
public DirectionFinder(DirectionFinderListener listener, String origin, String destination) {
    this.listener = listener;
    this.origin = origin;
    this.destination = destination;
}
```

**DirectionFinderListener.java**

```
import java.util.List;


public interface DirectionFinderListener {
    void onDirectionFinderStart();
    void onDirectionFinderSuccess(List<Route> route);
}
```

However the error lies in the try section saying that

> Error:(123, 33) error: incompatible types: MapsActivity cannot be
>   converted to DirectionFinderListener.

Any idea how do I solve this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure MapsActivity.java implements DirectionFinderListener.

Answer (score 1):

**MapsActivity** should implement `DirectionFinderListener` interface.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help !